# Using a constructor function to push objects onto an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, constructor

I know I'm way off, but I can't find any reading that's helped me solve this.  I'm trying to use a constructor function to create an array filled with Questions, Choices, and Answers for a quiz.  I'm not sure of the syntax to push my object onto the array.

My constructor function is as follows:

```
// Create array to traverse(using jQuery) so that on clicking submit, the current question
//is deleted, and the next question in the array is loaded.
var questionsArray = [];

//Contructor Function to create questions and push them to the array
function Question (question, choices, answer){
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
    return questionsArray.push();  //This is way off I know, but I'm lost...
}
```

Comment: `push(…)` takes an argument. *What* do you want to push, the new `Question` instance? You'd need to pass `this`, but actually it would be better to call `questionsArray.push(new Question(…))` from *outside* the constructor. Btw, you should not `return` anything from a constructor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`questionsArray.push(new Question('how?',['a','b','c'],'a'));`

and in your Question the push seems to be unnecessary

```
function Question (question, choices, answer){
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}
```

On creating the next form use `var current_question = questionsArray.shift();`, which takes first element off the array and shifts the rest. Alternatively, use questionsArray.pop() to get the last ones from the queue.

For incrementing the array itself, you could do it in the constructor - you could end Question function with `questionsArray.push(this);` but I'd rather use an external function to create questions and insert them into this array.

Comment: This. I couldn't have said it better.